# POJO object for this XML response in kotlin

Tags: java, xml, jackson, kotlin

I'm working with an API which returns XML something like this:

```
<xyz-objects version="1.0">
    <object pk="1" model="roll">
        <field type="BigIntegerField" name="roll_number">1000000714</field>
        <field type="CharField" name="status">DL</field>
        <field name="scans">
            <object pk="1" model="scan_stages">
                <field type="DateTimeField" name="updated_on">11 Jul, 2017, 17:40</field>
            </object>
        </field>        
    </object>
</xyz-objects>
```

I'm using Jackson's XML mapper.

I tried writing a POJO object for this but that doesn't work.

How do I handle attributes of elements like type and name?
Can you exemplify?

Comment: “I tried writing ...” - good! Relevant portions of your code? Any error (what error *exactly*)?

Comment: First of all: your XML is not valid :) `xyz-objects` is closed by `ecomexpress-objects`. Also you're missing `</field>` for `scans`. Obviously typos.

Comment: @madhead that is done..now please answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you didn't provide the schema, it's hard to guess some parts of your model. Especially, it's hard to guess `field` model. So I will deserialize it into a [`JsonNode`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html), dynamic object that can handle literally everything. [`JsonIgnoreProperties`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html) just in case you have some extra fields, not mentioned here.

First, create some data classes:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "xyz-objects")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
data class XyzObjects(
        @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
        val version: String,

        @JsonProperty(value = "object")
        @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
        val objects: List<Object>
)

@XmlRootElement(name = "object")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
data class Object(
        @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
        val pk: String,

        @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
        val model: String,

        @JsonProperty(value = "field")
        @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
        val fields: List<JsonNode>
)
```

Answering your question: you can handle attrributes with by using `isAttribute` attribute of [`JacksonXmlProperty`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-xml/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/annotation/JacksonXmlProperty.html). Lists can be handled with [`JacksonXmlElementWrapper`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-xml/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/annotation/JacksonXmlElementWrapper.html) + [`JsonProperty`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) (don't be fooled by name, it is used to handle plurals in names, thus making them more human readable in XML too).

In order to be able to work with data classes, you'll need to register [Kotlin module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin) with `registerKotlinModule`:

```
val text = """<xyz-objects version="1.0">
<object pk="1" model="roll">
    <field type="BigIntegerField" name="roll_number">1000000714</field>
    <field type="CharField" name="status">DL</field>
    <field name="scans">
        <object pk="1" model="scan_stages">
            <field type="DateTimeField" name="updated_on">11 Jul, 2017, 17:40</field>
        </object>
    </field>
</object>
</xyz-objects>"""
val mapper = XmlMapper().registerKotlinModule()
val node = mapper.readValue<XyzObjects>(text)

println(node)
```

It will print:

```
XyzObjects(version=1.0, objects=[Object(pk=1, model=roll, fields=[{"type":"BigIntegerField","name":"roll_number","":"1000000714"}, {"type":"CharField","name":"status","":"DL"}, {"name":"scans","object":{"pk":"1","model":"scan_stages","field":{"type":"DateTimeField","name":"updated_on","":"11 Jul, 2017, 17:40"}}}])])
```

Comment: this returns "Argument #0 has no property name annotation; must have name when multiple-parameter constructor annotated as Creator" then I add localName property to elements and then it returns: "Parameter specified as non-null is null: parameter pk"

Comment: It's just an example. Without knowing your full schema I cannot predict the exact types. Here, see: "Parameter specified as non-null is null: parameter pk" I didn't expect `pk` to be null in some cases, because all your examples had it. For this particular case use nullable types: `val pk: String?`

Comment: I used the same XML as in this question

Comment: No you didn't. In that XML **all** `Object` have non-null `pk`.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the investigation I did in https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin/issues/138 here's a workaround that's a bit more typed that the [`JsonNode` workaround by madhead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47124451/253468)

```
data class Field(
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    val type: String,

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    val name: String,
) {
    @JacksonXmlText
    lateinit var value: String private set
}
```